# show connection URL in tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, web-applications

I have a webapp on tomcat that keeps not being able to connect to a MySQL database and I don't have the source code for it. Is there a way to see the URL that it is trying to connect to? The exception trace just says communications error and it's not very helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky it will be defined in META-INF/context.xml, in a Resource element.